# How to get time entered by user in EditText and deduct 5 hrs 30 minutes from it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, simpledateformat, android-timepicker

I had two edit text for user to enter time (24 hours format).
How could i get those times from Edittext and deduct 5 hours and 30 minutes from user selected time.

Reason for deducting time : Converting IST to UTC timezone.

My final output should be like -  HH:MM:SS:Milleseconds (Ex : 18:25:30:245635).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is so easy to do, what have you tried ?

Comment: I've tried using SimpleDate format and Date class for parsing. But the result is not as expected.

Comment: Consider [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) rather than the poorly designed and old `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Yes, you can use java.time on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: My concern is that subtracting 5:30 will not always be correct. It has been India’s offset from UTC since WWII, but not always and it may not always stay that way. Can we assume a date?

Comment: @OleV.V. - So, what do you suggest me to get desired result. Anything example will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    String timeString = "18:25:30.245635";
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString);
    LocalTime utcTime = LocalDate.now(zone)        // Today
            .atTime(time)                          // Today at the time in question
            .atZone(zone)                          // Date and time in IST
            .toOffsetDateTime()                    // Convert to OffsetDateTime for the next step
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC) // Convert to UTC
            .toLocalTime();                        // Extract only the time of day
    System.out.println("UTC time: " + utcTime);
```

Output is:

> UTC time: 12:55:30.245635

I have assumed today’s date. Please check if this assumption is right for you. While the UTC offset for Asia/Kolkata hasn’t changed much recently, other time zones change their offset twice a year.

I changed your time format to have a period (point) rather than a colon between the seconds and fraction of second as is customary. If you do require a colon there, you need a `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: - Thanks dude, you really saved my time.